# Session Variable getting only one value

Tags: php

I am trying to get the radio button values from the page "add_attendance.php" through session variable and process it in "store_attendance.php"
Here is the code of add_attendance.php

```
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
                    {
                        $radio = 1;

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                         {

                            $radio_arr = array();
                            array_push($radio_arr, $radio);

                        $name_array[] = $row["Name"];
                        $_SESSION['name_array'] = $name_array;
                        $roll_array[] = $row["RollNo"];
                        $_SESSION['roll_array'] = $roll_array;

                            $_SESSION['radioKeys'] = $radio_arr;
                            isset($radio);
```

Here is the code of "store_attendance.php" that gets the radio button value and outputs.

```
   <?php

session_start();
$posted = array();

if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password']))
{

                    var_dump($_SESSION['name_array']); echo "<br>";
                    var_dump($_SESSION['roll_array']);echo "<br>";
                    //var_dump($_SESSION['radioKeys']);

                        foreach ($_SESSION['radioKeys'] as $radioKey) {
                            # code...
                        if (isset($_POST[$radioKey])) {
                            $posted[$radioKey] = $_POST[$radioKey];
                          }
                        }

                        $_SESSION['radio'] = $posted;
                        foreach ($_SESSION['radio'] as $radioKey => $radioValue)
                        {  
                                var_dump($radioValue);
                        }
}
```

The output i get is

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "Dhatchana" [1]=> string(6) "Deepak" }
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" }
array(1) { [0]=> int(2) } **string(7) "present"**
```

**string(7) "present"** the value i select in the second radio button. But i want both the values. What am i doing it wrong here ? thanks in advance.

Comment: did you not start the session in the first block of code? btw, this is unsafe `$_SESSION['password']`, you shouldn't store passwords in sessions.

Comment: started the session. but didnt include in the code here. It worked perfect fine just by using **$_SESSION['radioKeys'] = $radio;** back then. After sometime started throwing  "invalid argument supplied for foreach()" in the store_attendance.php page. so i just created a array `$radio_arr = array();
                            array_push($radio_arr, $radio)`

Comment: You are storing in one key so only last item will be saved in session

Comment: how do i store both the keys ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
`if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 

            {
                $radio = 1;

                    $radio_arr = array();



                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                 {

                    array_push($radio_arr, $radio);


                    $name_array[] = $row["Name"];
                    $_SESSION['name_array'] = $name_array;
                    $roll_array[] = $row["RollNo"];
                    $_SESSION['roll_array'] = $roll_array;



                    $_SESSION['radioKeys'] = $radio_arr;
                    isset($radio_arr);`
```